# How do I use ogr2ogr with python GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr2ogr

I've just installed GDAL, but I don't know how to import/use `ogr2ogr`.

I've tried:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
```

and searched both for `ogr2ogr`, but it wasn't there.

Comment: I think the link in the answer is a much more likely duplicate @Simbamangu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the answer posted by @elevine:

[How do I use ogr2ogr to convert a GML to shapefile in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/how-do-i-use-ogr2ogr-to-convert-a-gml-to-shapefile-in-python)

There is a ogr2ogr Python port which you can get here:

http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py