# Plotting Storm Prediction Center (SPC) Shapefile using Python?

Tags: python, shapefile

I am trying to make a plot of the SPC's thunderstorm outlook using Python. I have downloaded the shapefile from this website http://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/day1otlk.html. Then I use this code to try to read the data.

```
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    #draw basemap
    m=Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=20,urcrnrlat=50,llcrnrlon=-130,\
      urcrnrlon=-60,resolution='c')
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries()
    m.drawstates()
    m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#FFFFFF')
    shp_info = m.readshapefile('..\day1otlk_20140709_2000_cat','thunder')
```

But then I get ValueError: Shapefile must have lat/lon vertices - it appears this one
    has vertices in map projection coordinates. Convert the shapefile to
    geographic coordinates using the shpproj utility from the shapelib
    tools.

I am pretty new to this but I understand I need to convert this shapefile to geographic coordinates but the error message is too vague and I have no idea how.

Comment: What software are you using? QGIS, ArcGIS, etc? And version

Comment: Given the `m.readshapefile` and other commands, looks like Matlab.

Comment: Right now I am only using Python. Is there another way to do it? I am not familiar with QGIS or ArcGIS

Comment: The `shpproj` utility referred to in the error message [can be downloaded here](http://shapelib.maptools.org). It looks like a pretty straightforward tool ([documentation](http://shapelib.maptools.org/shapelib-tools.html#shpproj)), although I've never tried it and can't vouch for its usability.

Comment: Do I run shpproj with Python or do I need something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ogr2ogr to reproject the shapefile. I would probably just write a shell script to call ogr2ogr before calling your python script, but there is a Python interface to ogr2ogr. It's explained [here.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/how-do-i-use-ogr2ogr-to-convert-a-gml-to-shapefile-in-python) (That example is how to convert gml to shapefile. Near the bottom of [this page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) you can find an example of how to reproject, though not the python part.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the shapefiles [here](http://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/archive/2014/day1otlk_20140710_1300-shp.zip) all they contain is a field DN with numeric values.
There is no X or Y coordinate. In order to plot anything spatially there needs to be a reference. In python I am not sure if you can do this. The shapefiles provided are polygons and lines which are meant to overlay a basemap or surface of America.

However, if you are using a software solution like ArcGIS you can add these shapefiles and they will project on the fly.

If I'm looking at the wrong dataset please let me know - or perhaps attach it to your post so I can be more useful.

Comment: Yes this is the right dataset. Obviously the set is updated and renamed every few hours but the idea is still the same. I was able to plot it on a US map in QGIS, but I was hoping to have something a little more automated.