# Making CRS transformation of QgsVectorLayer with PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgsvectorlayer

I need to transform `QgsVectorLayers` in PyQGIS from one CRS into another. By googling I found the following solution [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/crs.html#crs-transformation), which works for points only:

```py
crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)    # WGS 84
crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32633)  # WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)
pt1 = xform.transform(QgsPoint(18, 5))
```

Is there a way to make a CRS transformation of an entire layer?

Comment: Are you wanting to make a new layer (shapefile etc.) with the new coordinate system?

Comment: no, i have a layer read from a shapefile, whereby the crs of the shapefile differs from the crs of the project. Now I want to transform the geodate (crs shapefile to crs project) just after reading so that I do not have to concern it later on (eg. geom.exportToWkt())

Comment: Why not just project the whole layer using OGR2OGR, that way it's already in the right coordinate system, no need for fancy code. I've not seen anything in *any* API to project a whole layer, it's done a single geometry at a time - the same way OGR2OGR does it.

Comment: ok, good idea, however, at the office, i am not allowed to install any software :(  thus, ogr2ogr is not an option

Comment: If you have QGIS you also have OGR2OGR, it's in the .\bin folder.

Comment: ok, i will check this :)

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: this answer seems answered by your comments, but it doesn't have a proper answer. Would you like to expand the comments into an answer, or should I do it myself?

Comment: Go right ahead @PavelV. , just remember to credit the comments (out of courtesy) or others may accuse you of plagiarism.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "Reproject layer" algorithm.

### QGIS 3

See [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#reproject-layer) for more details.

```py
params = {
    'INPUT': inputLayer, 
    'TARGET_CRS': 'EPSG:32633',
    'OUTPUT': "path/to/layerInUtm33N.shp"
}

processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", params)
```

### QGIS 2

See [the documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools.html#reproject-layer) for more details.

```py
processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', inputLayer, 'EPSG:32633', "path/to/layerInUtm33N.shp")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can directly use a loop in pyqgis to apply the same transformation `xform` to all features in a `QgsVectorLayer` and create a transformed layer in the new CRS, just as you transformed the single point in the question.

The loop to create *e.g.* a transformed `scratchLayer2` from `scratchLayer1`:

```
feats = []
for f in scratchLayer1.getFeatures():
    g = f.geometry()
    g.transform(xform)
    f.setGeometry(g)
    feats.append(f)

scratchLayer2.dataProvider().addFeatures(feats)
```

The code uses [`QgsGeometry::transform`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a677109c6f0f7751ba8475de537048de4) , so it applies to points, linestring as well as other feature types.

Below is a test (QGIS 3) on transforming a memory polyline layer.

```
crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)    # WGS 84
crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(32633)  # WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)

#create test layers    
uri1 = "linestring?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:integer"
scratchLayer1 = QgsVectorLayer(uri1, "Scratch point layer1",  "memory")

feat = QgsFeature(scratchLayer1.pendingFields())
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPointXY(18, 5),QgsPointXY(18, 6)]))
(res, outFeats) = scratchLayer1.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])

uri2 = "linestring?crs=epsg:32633&field=id:integer"
scratchLayer2 = QgsVectorLayer(uri2, "Scratch point layer2",  "memory")

#CRS transformation
feats = []
for f in scratchLayer1.getFeatures():
    g = f.geometry()
    g.transform(xform)
    f.setGeometry(g)
    feats.append(f)


scratchLayer2.dataProvider().addFeatures(feats)

#show results:    
for f in scratchLayer2.getFeatures():
    print(f.geometry().exportToWkt())
```

Output of the test:

> LineString (832713.79872411652468145 553423.98688296671025455,
>   832157.79170280916150659 664114.16206580714788288)

Comment: Thank you! That is the straightforward solution that I was hoping to avoid. Vincent_v_E's answer uses a builtin processing module which seems to be as clean and perfect as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

I do this in a plugin that I wrote, source code is here: https://github.com/icsm-au/icsm_qgis_transformer

The important part is this:

```
    dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
    dest_crs.createFromProj4(proj_string)

    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    temp_outfilename = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'temp_file.shp')
    error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, temp_outfilename, 'utf-8', dest_crs, 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

That is doing a transform while writing out to file. If you want the file to be temporary, you could transform into a virtual layer, I think.

Edit: super quick edit, but reading comments makes me think that what you want is to do a transform like above, resulting in a virtual (in memory) file. That's how QGIS works, you can't just have it magically converting, unless you use the built in on-the-fly reprojection.

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelMiles-Stimson suggested [OGR2OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), which is packed with QGIS. One option is to use it through command line, with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs epsg:32633 new.shp old.shp
```

You might prefer to call this command directly from python. [Elevine's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41637/12768) elsewhere shows how:

1) download http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/ogr2ogr.py and store it somewhere in your python import path (`/usr/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages` or `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages` on Linux, not sure about Windows)

2) write following code:

```
import ogr2ogr

ogr2ogr.main(["","-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-s_srs", "epsg:4326", "-t_srs", "epsg:32633", "new.shp", "old.shp"])
```

In case of bugs you might need to add full paths to the file names.

EDIT: alternative way, less bug-prone:

```
from os import system

#define oldPath and newPath
cmd = 'ogr2ogr -f ESRI Shapefile -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:32633 '+newPath+' '+oldPath
os.system(cmd)
```

Perhaps you can use `system(cmd)` instead, not sure which syntax is "better".

EDIT2: now I think the better way is to write the command and the call it, but function `call()` is prefered for it. See [a detailed post on SO on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/1801588).