# Merge all features in polygon shapefile with gdal

Tags: gdal, sqlite

How do I apply using this same concept,  but simply merging all features into one?

```
ogr2ogr output.shp input.shp -dialect sqlite -sql 
"SELECT ST_Union(geometry), dissolve_field FROM input GROUP BY dissolve_field"
```

Comment: Remove the group by?

Comment: I don't know... That's part of where I'm stuck. It doesn't seem to like a * as a wildcard. And ideas?

Comment: Where do you have a wildcard? `SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM input` I would think.

Comment: I tried that too but I don't know what to put in place of input

Comment: It is the layer name. You can check the name with ogr2ogr but with shapefiles it is the base name of the shapefile: input.shp -> input, foo.shp -> foo.

Comment: And geometry should be, in my case polygon, right?

Comment: I'm having issues still. the 32768.shp has an attribute named BLOCK and it's still not working.. any ideas?
>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp 32768.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_union(block) from '32768'"
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'ST_union(block)' to 'ST_union(b'

Comment: Does anyone have any more input on this one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to merge all features into one, you should do:

```
ogr2ogr output.shp input.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM input"
```

where `geometry` is the special field used in order to represent the geometry of the features in [SQLite SQL dialect](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html) and `input` in the SQL statement is the input layer name.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I believe your solution is the same as what ended up working for me:
>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp 32768.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_union(geometry) from '32768'"

Comment: I would like to apply this script on Python like this question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-gml-to-shapefile-in-python. I am a bit confused with the arguments though. I run this one: ogr2ogr.main(["","-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "output.shp", "input.shp", '-dialect sqlite', '-sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM input"' but it did not work out. How many arguments are there?

Comment: @IliasMachairas This does not work for GDAL 3.4.2 . I get an error about an incorrect number of argument supplied to ST_UNION. I downgraded to GDAL 3.2.2 and it worked fine. I have not tested it on the latest version of GDAL.

Comment: @IliasMachairas Actually I do not think the version of GDAL is the issue. I think some system dependency is causing this (possible sqlite/spatialite). I suggest using the official GDAl ubuntu full docker images for this task.