# Unable to open datasource with ogr2ogr.main()

Tags: python, ogr2ogr

I try to make ogr2ogr work in Python the way suggested by [Elevine's answer elsewhere](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41637/12768), but I'm facing bugs. Most notable error is that while I try to reproject shapefiles, I get the following error:

```
Unable to open datasource `lesy_w.shp' with the following drivers.
```

A list of formats follow, including "ESRI SHapefile". My command looks like this:

```
ogr2ogr.main(["", "-f","ESRI Shapefile", "-s_srs","epsg:4326", "-t_srs","epsg:32633", "lesy_u.shp","lesy_w.shp"])
```

The corresponding ogr2ogr command (`ogr2ogr -f ESRI Shapefile -t_srs epsg:32633 lesy_u.shp lesy_w.shp`) works well in the command line. It's a simple line geometry, no "geometry collection". The input shapefile (`lesy_w.shp`) is loaded as a QGIS layer normally. I tested this with other layers and the problem is still there.

I get the same error also while trying other operations, like converting to `KML` without reprojection. The same when I try to convert from `kml` to `shapefile`.

Is filing this as a bug in ogr2ogr.main() my only option, or is there any solution?

Comment: Is the typo in `-s_srs","eps:4326"` only in your question or in the code as well?

Comment: @user30184: in my code as well. I've corrected it, but the error remains.

Comment: The error can also mean that "lesy_w.shp" can't be found because it is not in the default path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python code, you can  not be sure in which folder the ogr command will be executed. In most cases, your data files will **not** be in a path included by the `PATH` variable, or the path where `ogr2ogr.exe` is located.

Therefore it is always safe to add the full pathnames to source and destination files (for the python command as well as on the command line).