# Using ogr2ogr in python?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geojson, ogr2ogr, json

I found this helpful post that got me started using ogr2ogr in python: [Using ogr2ogr to convert GML to shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/how-do-i-use-ogr2ogr-to-convert-a-gml-to-shapefile-in-python) as well as this one: [Converting ArcGIS Server JSON to GeoJSON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/how-to-convert-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson) I am trying to take JSON from arcgis service query results and convert to geojson. I am querying OBJECTIDs in increments of 1,000 as the query results limit is set to 1,000. I tested this and it works in command line, but when I run the script, I get an error saying unable to open data source. Can someone help?

```
import os
import ogr2ogr

def main():
    for i in range(0,83000,1000):
        url = ('https://gisrevprxy.seattle.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/SDOT_EXT/sdot_parking/MapServer/5/query?'
               'text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&'
               'relationParam=&objectIds=&where=OBJECTID%3E+'+str(i)+'&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly='
               'false&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=OBJECTID%2CShape%2CSEGKEY%'
               '2CELMNTKEY%2CDISTANCE%2CWIDTH%2CSIGNTYPE%2CSTANDARDTEXT%2CCATEGORY&f=pjson')

        outfile = os.path.join('/Users/kirsten_lawrence/Documents','recs_'+str(i)+'up.json')
        # note: main is expecting sys.argv, where the first argument is the script name
        # so, the argument indices in the array need to be offset by 1
        print 'creating geojson starting at record',i
        ogr2ogr.main(['','-f', 'GeoJSON', outfile, url, 'OGRGeoJSON'])
```

Comment: I confirmed his url works with [i=0](http://bit.ly/28NCjVs) and [i=2000](http://bit.ly/28Pl1uc). Also I'd never seen that multi-line string syntax before, but [it checks out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/786131).. For sanity you might try invoking ogr2ogr command line programmatically, like this: `os.system(ogr2ogr_terminal_instruction)` My assumption is something must be wrong with how your submitting your arguments to `ogr2ogr.main()`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I can certainly do that, though I wish I could get this working. Is it pretty much equivalent to use os.system or subprocess.call?