# Sentinel-2 cloud mask with fmask

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, cloud-cover

I'm trying to run fmask on a Sentinel-2 granule.
I downloaded the 3.2 version of Windows stand alone software for Sentinel 2 from https://github.com/prs021/fmask
When I try to run fmask by calling the FmaskMSI.exe through cmd from the folder containing the Sentinel-2 Granule (or from within the granule folder) i get the following error:

```
No L*MTL.txt header in the current folder!
Output argument "clr_pct" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "autoFmask".
MATLAB:unassignedOutputs
```

The `L*MTL.txt` suggests that its's looking for a Landsat type product but i specifically point to the Sentinel-2 installation of fmask

How do i get fmask to run for Sentinel-2 data?

Comment: I searched a bit for this because I also need to implement fmask. I am trying to use the Python version of this algorithm, but I got stuck at reading the .xml metadata file. Maybe it will help you. This is the link to the Python package: http://pythonfmask.org/en/latest/#downloads  Let me know if you managed to perform the cloud correction. All the best!

Comment: Cross-posted: http://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-2-cloud-mask-with-fmask/4152

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cloud mask *.gml* file provided by ESA with the archive you download from the hub or other vendors.
You only need to convert the *.gml* file into *.shp.* I use GDAL's ogr2ogr to do this, a link for this conversion is here: [Using ogr2ogr to convert GML to shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-gml-to-shapefile-in-python)

Comment: The cloud mask provided by ESA does not have a satisfactory performance, that's why I am looking for alternatives.