# KML driver failed to create

Tags: python, gdal, ogr2ogr

I want to convert spatial data from postgres to some basic formats (shp, geopackage, csv, xlsx, gml... ) using python gdal functionality. I read the answer to this question: [Using ogr2ogr to convert GML to shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-gml-to-shapefile-in-python)

I downloaded ogr2ogr.py and tried to convert data from postgres to some formats but I get an error saying:

`KML driver failed to create /home/.../out.kml`

This is the method I am using:

```
 ogr2ogr.main(["", "-f", "KML", "/home/.../out.kml",
              "PG:dbname='dbname' host='host' port=5432 user='username' password='password'",
              "-sql", "SELECT column1, column2 FROM schema.table"])
```

Comment: Is the path correct and do you have rights to write there?

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. I gave permissions (read, write, execute) to everyone.

Comment: Three dots are strange `"/home/.../out.kml"` for a Unix file location.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the select column part but this should produce the entire table in kml:

```
ogr2ogr.main(["", "-f", "KML", "/home/.../out.kml",
              "PG:dbname='dbname' host='host' port=5432 user='username' password='password'","table"])
```