# Issue to convert from PostgreSQL input to GPKG using Python GDAL API function gdal.VectorTranslate

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr

When I run the following code, it fails with message

> The error is ERROR 1: SELECT from table mytable failed, no such table/featureclass.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()

gdal.VectorTranslate(  
    '/tmp/out.gpkg', 
    "PG:host=localhost dbname=mydatabase user=username password=mypassword port=5432",  
    SQLStatement='SELECT * FROM mytable',
    layerName='tablenameout'
)
```

The following alternate syntax failed too

```
gdal.VectorTranslate(  
    '/tmp/out.gpkg', 
    "PG:host=localhost dbname=mydatabase user=username password=mypassword port=5432",  
    options='-sql "SELECT * FROM mytable" -nln layernameout'
)
```

With ogr2ogr and providing the same input table name and database connexion, the conversion happened correctly.

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" /tmp/out.gpkg \
"PG:host=localhost user=username dbname=mydatabase password=mypassword port=5432" \
-sql "SELECT * FROM mytable" \
-nln tablenameout
```

What do I miss in my code syntax to make the Python API `gdal.VectorTranslate` works to open the database with my query without error?

Comment: Would it help to import also `ogr`?

Comment: Perhaps the PG connection should also be between `'...'`  instead of `"..."`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. The issue was not here but about connecting as "PostGISRaster" instead of "PostgreSQL"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was about opening implicitly with the "wrong" driver. Seen by setting `CPL_DEBUG` to `ON`. When I was trying to establish the connexion, I got

> GDAL: GDALOpen(PG:host=localhost user=username dbname=mydatabase password=XXX port=5432, this=0x2972350) succeeds as PostGISRaster.

Forcing the driver to understand my data source was vector (PostgreSQL driver), the table in the SELECT can be then found

```
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_DEBUG', 'ON')

conn_string = "PG:host=localhost dbname=mydatabase user=username password=mypassword port=5432"
ds = gdal.OpenEx(conn_string, gdal.OF_VECTOR)

# You can choose amongst following syntax

# Syntax 1
gdal.VectorTranslate(
    '/tmp/out.gpkg',
    ds,
    options='-f GPKG -sql "SELECT * FROM mytable" -nln layernameout'
)

# Syntax 2
gdal.VectorTranslate(
    '/tmp/out.gpkg',
    ds,
    SQLStatement='SELECT * FROM mytable',
    layerName='tablenameout',
    format='GPKG'
)

# Syntax 3
myoptions = {
    "SQLStatement": "SELECT * FROM mytable",
    "layerName": "tablenameout",
    "format": "GPKG"
}
gdal.VectorTranslate(
    '/tmp/out.gpkg',
    ds,
    **myoptions
)

# Syntax 4
gdal.VectorTranslate(
    '/tmp/out.gpkg',
    ds,
    options=gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(
        SQLStatement='SELECT * FROM mytable',
        layerName='tablenameout',
        format='GPKG'
    )
)

ds = None
```

Comment: Check out https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslateOptions for argument options

Comment: update: https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.VectorTranslateOptions