# PyQGIS: Prompt ogr2ogr error in the log window of the processing tool

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, ogr2ogr, error, ogrinfo

I have a processing tool that helps users to export data from PostGIS tables to GPKG. I am using `ogr2ogr` commands to achieve the tasks. I am calling the commands via subprocess. However, I cannot print out in the log window of the tool any error that may occur while executing the `ogr2ogr`. Is there any way to capture errors and display them in the log window? For now, the best I could do is a configuration option to create a log file at the end

> -debug on --config CPL_LOG  C:\Users\Export.log'

```
import subprocess
import asyncio
import time

outFile = r"C:\Users\INPUT_DATA.gpkg"
bwk_views = [
    ('view_1', 'output_1', 'POLYGON')
    ,('view_2', 'output_2', 'LINESTRING')]

commands = []

for view in bwk_views:
    layer_name = view[1]
    commands.append(
        f'ogr2ogr -update -append -f GPKG "{outFile}" PG:service=XX -sql "SELECT * FROM wlk.{view[0]}" -nln {layer_name} -nlt {view[2]} -a_srs EPSG:31287' )
        
async def export(delay, command):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)

async def main():

    # Wait tasks are completed one after another 
    for i, command in enumerate(commands):
        await export(i, command)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is related to the way you get the `process.run` output.

You may use

```
import subprocess

command = ["ogr2ogr", "input.shp", "output.shp"]
result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)

print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

Code borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171791/how-to-suppress-or-capture-the-output-of-subprocess-run

Personally, I would go the Python way using this recipe [Issue to convert from PostgreSQL input to GPKG using Python GDAL API function gdal.VectorTranslate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397023/issue-to-convert-from-postgresql-input-to-gpkg-using-python-gdal-api-function-gd) to get Python GDAL logs instead of mixing command line calls from Python  and then trying to get command line logs within Python.

The important part for logs are lines

```py
gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_DEBUG', 'ON')
```

By default, errors are thrown to stdout

To redirect them to file, you may add the same option you mentioned but in Python context

```
gdal.SetConfigOption('CPL_LOG_ERRORS', 'C:\Users\Export.log')
```